# Login validate with encrypted password in PHP

Tags: php, django, sha1

I have a PostgreSQL database, which have many users. Users' passwords are encrypted in this format:

```
sha1$678ae$0dd4b5a9588be91a931d1ef1f7e7053477c1478e
```

This encryption was done with Django (although I don't know if you can encrypt it directly in database).

What I'm trying to do is make a PHP application that can use and validate these users, with those encrypted passwords.

How could I do it?
PS: I'm using PHP 7.

Comment: You need to use the same encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Django stores passwords using the PBKDF2 hash (see their [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/)). Assuming you have not changed this default, you should be able to hash using PBKDF2 in PHP using the [hash_pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) function.

You'll need to accept a user's password in your PHP app, turn it into a PBKDF2 hash with the same `algo`, `salt`, `iterations`, and `length` that your Django app uses, and then compare the resulting value against the encrypted password in your Django database to see whether they match.